# Convert Isolated Storage /RAW Format into WMV on Client side

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, isolatedstorage

Currently we're trying to create a project which has access via web cam to capture
the Video and Audio and store it on Cache.

We have been able to successfully capture the Video into the "Isolated Storage" or "Raw" File format. The next step is to create a silverlight friendly format like WMV version 8 or 9 which can be used for Replay.

Asof now we have been able to successfully get a project from [Link](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/12/10/silverlight-4-more-on-capturing-video-from-webcams.aspx) 
 to capture the video and encode it into AVI format for replay mode. Unfortunately we've not been able to get a client version code snippet or API that allows encoding into WMV format directly.

Any pointers in the direction would be most appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

For the moment there is no easy solution for encoding video/audio raw format from SL, and I think SL5 does not have that capabilities as well.

The only solution I found when I had that question too, was from StreamCoders's SilverSuite product, but it was too pricey for my needs. You might have a look there:

http://www.streamcoders.com/products/silversuite.html

Another solution would be to upload the raw data to a server and perform the encoding there, problem is the size of the raw data file are so big that it make it even not suitable.

I tried to zip the raw file, for a 45 second video/audio I had ~ 320 MB file size and ~ 210 after zipping. That was still way too high for my need.

So far I've not see much hope encoding raw file from the client side apart from the StreamCoders products.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

We have been developing the same application as a Pure Silverlight Browser solution and moved towards an out of browser solution where -

- We capture the RAW Isolated Storage Format and convert it into AVI using AVIDLL available from the following urls -

  - [Silverlight 4 More on Capturing Videos from Webcams](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/12/10/silverlight-4-more-on-capturing-video-from-webcams.aspx)
  - [Silverlight 4 Yet More on Capturing Videos from Webcams](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/12/28/silverlight-4-yet-more-on-capturing-video-from-webcams.aspx)
- And later convert the AVI video (RAW->AVI)  which is still large into a WMV file using FFMpeg.exe

Statistics on SIZE:

- RAW atleast 700MB for a 1 min recording
- AVI atleast 600MB after conversion from RAW
- WMV atleast 500KB after conversion from AVI

Statistics on TIMELINE:

- RAW to AVI conversion takes about 1min for the 700MB conversion
- AVI to WMV conversion takes another 1min for the 600MB conversion

Comparing this with the RAW file upload to the server and converting it would be quite a time consuming process considering that the RAW file size is large.

Any optimizations which could help change the time taken to convert or perform a direct conversion to WMV could make the solution better.

Cheers !